# How to Set Zoom of Map to show all markers in tabpage Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I use this code for perform google maps in tab page but not show all markers in the tab.
how to set zoom google map for show all markers in the tab page. 
  "`map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);`" not worked in the TabPage.
how can i do it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<body>

<h1>My First Google Map</h1>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <h3>HOME</h3>
    <p>Some content.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 1</h3>

<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>Menu 2</h3>
    <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
function myMap() {
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, -0.2), zoom: 10
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
$(function () {
      $('a[href="#menu1"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
          var lastCenter = map.getCenter();
          google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
          map.setCenter(lastCenter);

      });
  });
var locations=[];
locations.push({neme:"Country1",latlng:new google.maps.LatLng(46.71285452819798, 20.36901795864105)});  
locations.push({neme:"Country2",latlng:new google.maps.LatLng(51.71285452819798, 10.36901795864105)});  
locations.push({neme:"Country3",latlng:new google.maps.LatLng(62.71285452819798, 30.36901795864105)});  

var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

for(var i=0;i<locations.length;i++)
{

   var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: locations[i].latlng,
                map: map,
                title:locations[i].name
               //zoom:8
            });
latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);
}

//Get the boundaries of the Map.
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        //Center map and adjust Zoom based on the position of all markers.
        map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?your-key-Api&callback=myMap"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because your map is not ready yet. you need to use map callback. jQuery.ready doesn't catch map.ready.

```
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

all your map related functionality should be inside the initMap function or should be called inside it.

Comment: I had known it before.But the main issue is that using "  map.fitBounds(latlngbounds); " Inside Tap Page doesn't display all markers. If I put tag :<div id="map" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div> out of tab so every is gonna be okay but inside tab is not working properly.  would you please give me a suggestion how to solve this problem.

Comment: Who is friend suggested Give me a solution?